# Can I configure the second micro-USB port for ADB shell instead of debug?

Tags: adb, adb-drivers, adbd

i am working a android based module and it has two micro-usb ports, one is used to connect to adb shell and the other is for debug. Can i be able to configure the debug micro-usb so that i can use it to connect to adb shell? If yes, please help me with the procedure.

I have tried to find the service for adb and i have found one which is adbd, and now i am trying how it is used to configure.

Comment: What type of "debug" are you talking about? I think you should contact the manufacturer of the Android based module for your answers.